# Discrete Maths-Logic

Tags: logic

> *I like blueberry pie.*
>
> Cannibalism is savage.
>
> Jack is heading to school.
>
> It is cold.

**Facebook is fun.**

Are they prepositions?

Can you explain me how to identify whether a statement is preposition?

Comment: They're *definitely* not [prepositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition).  Perhaps you meant to ask if they were [propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition)?

Comment: I think so do you know by the way why 1 v 0 equivalent to 1

Comment: Because the truth value of $p \lor q$ is the max between the truth value of $p$ and that of $q$.

Comment: but what is the inner meaning is it just accepted like that.

Comment: And why is it cold is not a preposition?

Comment: Is it postulate of boolean algebra?

Comment: Please edit the post to improve it. What is the definition of 'proposition' you are using? Which ones do you think are propositions, and why?

Comment: What is the definition of **preposition** you are using? Is it the same as the definition of **proposition** that [Mauro](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/108274/mauro-allegranza) writes in the answer? If so, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

For :

> "how to identify whether a statement is proposition"

see :

- Kenneth Rosen, [Discrete mathematics and its applications](https://www.amazon.it/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/0073383090/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (7th ed), page 2:

> A **proposition** is a declarative sentence (that is, a sentence that declares a fact) that is either true or false, but not both.